# python compatibility friendly dictionary methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, compatibility, backwards-compatibility

where can one find information on methods of dictionaries that are most forward/backwards compatible? for example, things that are unchanged between python 2.5 onward and are also going to be supported in python3?

for example: I am not sure if `d.itervalues()` is a backward/forward compatible method to use? I use it to get a single element from a dictionary:

```
# is this good form for those who care about compatibility?
d = {"foo": {"bar": []}}
elt = next(d.itervalues())
```

Comment: a dictionary has no order in Python. `elt` may change from run to run for the same `dict`. To get *some* value from a dict without `six.itervalues()` in backward/forward compatible way: `d[next(iter(d))]`. btw, `next()` builtin is available only in Python 2.6+

Comment: @JFSebastian: I can settle for 2.6+ support so if `next(iter(d))` works in Python 3 and does not require loading the whole list in memory which doesn't look like it does then that's the answer

Answer (score 3):

For this specific method dictionary.**itervalues()**, it changed to dictionary.**values()** in Python 3.

Check this library that addresses the compatibility issues between Python 2 &3

https://pythonhosted.org/six/

Comment: It's quite frustrating that such a basic core feature changes names and recommended idioms between releases. Basically there's no good method that works across releases for this then? I will not use ``values()`` since that will break older pythons

Comment: Agree :) maybe the Six library will be handy in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It would be forward compatible to use `.values()` if that is unlikely to be a very large list when materialized in memory.

To be certain, you can do this:

```
d = {"foo": {"bar": []}}
elt = next(iter(d.values()))
```

and elt returns

```
{'bar': []}
```

I personally tested that this works in Python 2.6 & 3.3, but [iter was first available in 2.2.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter)

The code would be forward compatible, and then you could clean up the `iter` parts when you no longer wish for support in 2.

Comment: isn't ``values()`` going to load it all into memory? The goal was not to